# Activating python virtual environment and error - Set-ExecutionPolicy : Cannot set execution policy

Tags: python, scope, virtual-environment, executionpolicy, pyvenv

I want to activate my already created Python virtual environment.I used "./activate" command in the /venv/Scripts . But, then I got the following error.

> .\activate: File D:\Automation_Testing_with_Azure_Pipeline\AutomationProject-v1\AutomationProject-v1\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file D:\Automation_Testing_with_Azure_Pipeline\AutomationProject-v1\AutomationProject-v1\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current system. For more
> information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

My execution policy list is as below.

```
 Get-ExecutionPolicy -List                                                

    Scope ExecutionPolicy
    ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
UserPolicy       Undefined
Process       Undefined
CurrentUser    RemoteSigned
LocalMachine    RemoteSigned
```

I tried to change "MachinePolicy" and "UserPolicy" as well using following command.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope MachinePolicy
```

But,it gives this error.

> Set-ExecutionPolicy : Cannot set execution policy. Execution policies at the MachinePolicy or UserPolicy scopes must
> be set through Group Policy.

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this?